# Counting instances and displaying in new column with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Having a problem getting this query to work. I can get it all except for the **Count** column. I know its simple but there's something I'm just not getting here. Please see problem below.

List the first name, middle name and last name from the Employees table, and the shipping city and their total number or count from the Orders table. Only display the shipping city if the count of the shipping city is greater than or equal to 7. Display the first name of the employee followed by a space followed by the middle name followed by a space followed by the last name but do not leave a space if the employee does not have a middle name. Order the result set by the employee name. The query should produce the result set listed below.

[image]

```
SELECT        CONCAT(Employees.FirstName,' ',Employees.MiddleName, ' ', Employees.LastName) AS Name,
              Orders.ShipCity
FROM          Employees INNER JOIN
              Orders ON Employees.EmployeeID = Orders.EmployeeID
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do :-

```
SELECT        CONCAT(Employees.FirstName,' ',Employees.MiddleName, ' ', Employees.LastName) AS Name,
              Orders.ShipCity,
              COUNT(1) [Count]
FROM          Employees INNER JOIN
              Orders ON Employees.EmployeeID = Orders.EmployeeID
GROUP BY Employees.FirstName, Employees.MiddleName, Employees.LastName, Orders.ShipCity
```

Comment: Thanks, Chamika, that really helps. I just had to add 'HAVING COUNT(*) >=7' on to the end of it.

Comment: Oho sorry I didn't see that part. Glad that you got it done mate :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `COUNT` as an analytic function:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(e.FirstName, ' ', e.MiddleName, ' ', e.LastName) AS Name,
    o.ShipCity,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY e.EmployeeID) [Count]
FROM Employees e
INNER JOIN Orders o
    ON e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID;
```